# how to create spinner list in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I was struggling to make a `listView` in android as shown in the picture below
[image]

My purpose of showing the picture is that how to make two android `listView`'s which  spin around and those should be selected at middle of them as that of shown in picture. If Any one please have any idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are searching for this. [android wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)

Comment: ok! but how can I be able to make my own `listView` like this?

Comment: there is also an example inside this. please try to understand that.

Comment: I have downloaded an example of this from http://www.android-ever.com/2011/06/android-wheel-picker-example.html but there is problem of library project not found how to fix that?

Comment: i also tried the code which you are trying but i also got some errors and didnt try to fix them. please try the code i provided you.

Comment: i gave you some link. go to download tab and you will find several examples. you can try to understand those.

Answer (score 1):

There is an opensource library which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) In the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5ncm9pZGlmeS51aXBhdHRlcm5zIl0.) demo
Demo -> Picker-> Android-wheel to get to the demo.